# Newly added property in log4j-DailyRollingFileAppender is not found

Tags: java, log4j

I was trying to have log4j roll log files on daily basis with a maxBackUpIndex.
This as per many blogs and documentation is not available.
So from some blog, I figured out that we can update the DailyRollingFileAppender class file itself to have maxBackupIndex property and its implementation.

I was able to add the new implementation and replace the original DailyRollingFileAppender file with new updated one.

But the updated log4j.jar does not reflect my change, it says "log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"

Please suggest, if anyone has encountered something similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the class file was not getting complied - copied in the jar properly.

Created the jar from jar - cvf command and it worked fine.